# Simplify $(-2\sin(t)-2\sin(2t))^2+(2\cos(t)-2\cos(2t))^2$?

Tags: trigonometry, factoring

In calculating the length of a deltoid one gets the following string of trigonometric functions:

$$(-2\sin(t)-2\sin(2t))^2+(2\cos(t)-2\cos(2t))^2$$
$$=4\big(\sin^2(2t)+2\sin(t)\sin(2t)+\cos^2(2t)-2\cos(t)\cos(2t)+\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)\big)$$
$$(\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1)$$
$$=4\big(1+2\sin(t)\sin(2t)-2\cos(t)\cos(2t)+1\big)$$

Question is, how to simplify this further?

Comment: is there a typo in your formula?

Comment: Use the rule $$ \cos(\alpha\pm\beta)=\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)\mp\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$$

Comment: probably a minus sign is missing

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\ldots &= 4\big(1 +2\sin(t)\sin(2t) -2\cos(t)\cos(2t) +1\big) \\
&=4(2 -2\cos 3t) \\
&=8(1 -\cos 3t) \\
&=16 (\sin ( 3 t/2) )^2 \\
&=\big( 4 \sin ( 3 t/2) \big)^2.
\end{align}

Comment: And that's using what identities?

Comment: @mavavlji, you can figure out the identities by looking at where you started and where you wound up ….

Comment: cosine of sum of two angles ; cos ( t +  2 t)

Answer (score 1):

Notice, 
$$4(1+2\sin t\sin 2t-2\cos t\cos 2t+1)$$
$$=8(1+\sin t\sin 2t-\cos t\cos 2t)$$
$$=8(1-(\cos t\cos 2t-\sin t\sin 2t)$$
using $\color{red}{\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B=\cos (A+B)}$, 
$$=8(1-\cos(t+2t))$$ $$=8(1-\cos 3t)$$
using $\color{red}{\cos A=1-2\sin^2\frac{A}{2}}$,
$$=8\left(1-\left(1-2\sin^2 \frac{3t}{2}\right)\right)$$
$$=8\left(1-1+2\sin^2 \frac{3t}{2}\right)$$
$$=8\left(2\sin^2 \frac{3t}{2}\right)=\color{blue}{16\sin^2 \frac{3t}{2}}$$